# How to convert controller action to be non-blocking/asynchronous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I have a controller action that accepts a file, parses the file and imports data from it, and returns a file:

```
    public FileResult ImportDevices()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase csvFile = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;

        if (csvFile != null || csvFile.ContentLength != 0)
        {
            SaveDevicesResult result = CADC.SaveCSVDeviceData(csvFile.InputStream);

            string csvString = result.ToString();

            UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvString);

            return File(bytes, "text/txt", "ImportResults.txt");
        }
        return null; // Not sure how to handle this case, that's another question though!
    }
```

And I'd like this to be non blocking, since the import can take awhile. I'd like the user to be able to browse the page, and return the file as a download when it's ready.

Do I follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Or do I using async and await?

Or are they the same thing and I'm confused?

Comment: try using a new Thread(http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a backgroundworker (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) and invoke what you want to return

Comment: I would make it open in a new tab and let it download to the new tab. Similar to how Google Drive does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write an asynchronous controller method to handle this, and you would also have to rewrite your `SaveCSVDeviceData` method to return a `Task<SaveDevicesResult>`. What you are trying to do here is done via the async/await pattern, which can be achieved by the following

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ImportDevicesAsync()
{
    var csvFile = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;
    if(csvFile != null && csvFile.ContentLength != 0)
    {
        // Note: I would recommend you do not do this here but in a helper class
        // for this to work, SaveCSVDeviceDataAsync *must* return a Task<object>()
        var result = await CADC.SaveCSVDeviceDataAsync(csvFile.InputStream);
        var csvString = result.ToString();
        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvString);
        // if you are returning a csv, return MIME type text/csv
        return File(bytes, "text/txt", "ImportResults.txt");
    }

    // If the file is null / empty, then you should return
    // a validation error
    return Error(500, ...);
}
```

As I mentioned though, in order for this to work your `CADC.SaveCsvDeviceData` must return a `Task<SaveDevicesResult>`. Given that you are passing that method an `InputStream` I will remind you that all methods on the `InputStream` have an awaitable alternative to them in .NET 4.5 +.

Comment: Rather than re-writing CADC.SaveCSVDeviceData, I can just write a wrapper, correct?

Comment: [No, and here is why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). If you have control over how that method is implemented I would recommend you create a new implementation called `SaveCSVDeviceDataAsync` that uses the async/await methodology. You don't need to remove the old method.

Comment: I'm thinking CADC.SaveCSVDevicesData is more CPU intensive where having it's own thread might be beneficial, rather than asynchronous processing. I can start CADC.SaveCSVDeviceData on a thread and await it in the async action, and this would leave the UI unblocked, correct?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same thing, the link that you posted is pertains to MVC 1.0 and it's an old way of doing it. For MVC 4 see [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: So in html I would post the file to /Controller/ImportDevicesAsync?

Comment: yes, you need to implement an `async` version of the method returning `Task<FileResult>`